# A SPARQL query that works in the DBpedia endpoint but not with ARC2

Tags: php, filter, sparql, dbpedia, arc2

the query is the following :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT distinct ?value
    from <http://fr.dbpedia.org>
    WHERE{                                          

        ?sub rdfs:label ?value.                     
                    FILTER (CONTAINS(LCASE(?value), 'data')).                                                           
        }

limit 10
```

it works perfectly fine using the [DBpedia endpoint](http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql) but when I try to use it from PHP using ARC2 I get the following error :

> Query errorsArray (  [0] => Incomplete FILTER in
>   ARC2_SPARQLPlusParser [ 1] => Incomplete or invalid Group Graph
>   pattern. Could not handle " " in ARC2_SPARQLPlusParser )

Any ideas what could be the problem ? 
thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC2 does **not** support full SPARQL 1.1 (see the [source code](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/blob/master/parsers/ARC2_SPARQLParser.php#L739-L748)), thus, `CONTAINS` is not supported. You can try to use `REGEX` instead:

PREFIX rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#

```sql
SELECT distinct ?value
    from <http://fr.dbpedia.org>
    WHERE{                                          

        ?sub rdfs:label ?value.                     
                    FILTER (REGEX(STR(?value), 'data', 'i')).                                                           
        }

limit 10
```